# Alamofire equivalent of AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, alamofire

With `AFNetworking` I followed the suggest pattern of creating an application specific subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`. Mine looked like this:

```
static NSString* Username = @"";
static NSString* Password = @"";
static NSString* BaseURL = @"https://abc.xyz.com:12345/";

@implementation HttpConnection

+ (HttpConnection*) current {
    static HttpConnection* current = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        current = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: BaseURL]];
        current.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        current.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        current.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    });
    [current.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername: Username password: Password];
    return current;
}
```

I'm curious how I should translate this pattern to use with `Alamofire`. Is it just something like the following?

```
static let BaseURL = "https://abc.xyz.com:12345/"
static var User = ""
static var Password = ""

func myAppRequest((method: Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL) -> Request {
    let request = Alamofire.request(method, BaseURL + URLString, parameters, encoding)
    request.authenticate(user: User, password: "Password)
    return request
}
```

Peeking in the `Alamofire` code, I have a hunch that it may be possible to manipulate `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance` at the appropriate times (baseURL at app startup, and User/Password whenever those change). But that's less obvious how one goes about that (if it's indeed possible).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Alamofire.Manager to handle all requests. This is how I do it.

```
//initialize with all details such as referrer etc
self.manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: cfg) 


let user = "user"
let password = "password"
// you may manipulate configuration later on if you want.
self.manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders!["Referer"] = self.host
self.manager.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
         .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
         .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")
                failure(res, json, error)
                return
            }
            else {
                 // do something with JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: mngr just pains my soul. Please, please, use actual words when naming things, for your sake and the sake of anyone who reads your code.

Comment: I don't want to cause any pain to your soul :) I renamed the variable.

Comment: So there's no way to get the `.authenticate` built into the configuration? Is the self.host/Referrer where you set what ends up being a BaseURL?

Comment: You can also do it like this even though it is hacky. You can choose .custom encoding and set the body and the header of the request as you wish. self.host is just an example variable which I was using. You don't need to set it if your host doesn't require it.

Comment: For future readers, please note that `Alamofire.Manager` is now `Alamofire.SessionManager`: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#namespace-changes